# Put variable in succes.phtml pixel for currency in Magento

Tags: php, magento

We are using a pixel for an affiliate campaign with the details below and we have a couple of variables in there for the order id and total amount that is paid. We have a multi currency shop (euro, pond) and need to put also a variable for the currency. Does anyone know how to setup the variable in the code beneath:

```
<?php
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$total = $order->getData('grand_total');
?>

<img src="http://domain.com/?&productID=&conversionType=sale&transactionID=<?php echo $this->getOrderId()?>&transactionAmount=<?= $total ?&currency=VARIABEL" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet will fetch currency code from order object

```
$currencyCode = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
```